# Debugging not working breakpoint not stopping Visual Studio Mac Javascript React

Tags: reactjs, macos, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on a Mac and I am developing a ASP Net server side with React SPA app.

I set the breakpoint just as I would if I was using VS for windows but when I run the app in debug mode it is not being hit in any of the react/JS code.

Breakpoints are showing proper but as soon as you execute in Debug mode breakpoints are shown as hollow circles, meaning they might be disabled? But they are shown as enabled when I right-click on them.

I have tried the same type of project in Visual Studio 2022 for windows and it works fine.

No article found on web so far.

It is getting more and more difficult to work to develop without ability to debug!

Answer (score 0):

I have reached out to Microsoft Visual Studio team and they confirmed that Javascript Debugging is not enabled for Visual Studio for Mac.